# Ros Fuerte on Lion OSX: make -j8

Tags: macos, macos-lion, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had to install a couple extra things to get here such as: brew install Qt
I went and installed wxPython on my own. I chose: wxPython2.9-osx-cocoa-py2.7 Maybe that is my issue, but I tried: wxPython2.8-osx-unicode-py2.7 as well to no avail.

I always get to 100% then it just bombs out like below.
Any ideas?

> ```
> [ 98%] Building CXX object ros_comm/tools/rosbag/CMakeFiles/rosbag.dir/src/message_instance.cpp.o
> [ 98%] Built target turtlesim_node
> [ 98%] Building CXX object ros_comm/tools/rosbag/CMakeFiles/rosbag.dir/src/player.cpp.o
> [ 98%] Building CXX object ros_comm/tools/rosbag/CMakeFiles/rosbag.dir/src/query.cpp.o
> [ 98%] Building CXX object ros_comm/tools/rosbag/CMakeFiles/rosbag.dir/src/recorder.cpp.o
> [ 98%] Building CXX object ros_comm/tools/rosbag/CMakeFiles/rosbag.dir/src/stream.cpp.o
> [ 98%] Building CXX object ros_comm/tools/rosbag/CMakeFiles/rosbag.dir/src/time_translator.cpp.o
> [ 98%] Building CXX object ros_comm/tools/rosbag/CMakeFiles/rosbag.dir/src/uncompressed_stream.cpp.o
> [100%] Building CXX object ros_comm/tools/rosbag/CMakeFiles/rosbag.dir/src/view.cpp.o
> Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/librxtools.dylib
> ld: warning: ignoring file /System/Library/Frameworks//QuickTime.framework/QuickTime,
> ```
>
> file was built for unsupported file
> format which is not the architecture
> being linked (x86_64)
> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
> "wxNavigationEnabled::SetFocus()",
> referenced from:
> vtable for rxtools::GenTopicDisplayDialog in
> topic_display_generated.cpp.o
> vtable for rxtools::TopicDisplayDialog in
> topic_display_dialog.cpp.o
> vtable for rxtools::RosoutSetupDialogBase in
> rosout_generated.cpp.o
> vtable for rxtools::TextboxDialog in
> rosout_generated.cpp.o
> vtable for rxtools::RosoutFrame in
> rosout_generated.cpp.o
> vtable for rxtools::LoggerLevelFrame in
> rosout_generated.cpp.o
> vtable for wxMDIParentFrameBase in
> rosout_generated.cpp.o
> ...
> "wxNavigationEnabled::AcceptsFocus()
> const", referenced from:
> vtable for rxtools::GenTopicDisplayDialog in
> topic_display_generated.cpp.o
> vtable for rxtools::TopicDisplayDialog in
> topic_display_dialog.cpp.o
> vtable for rxtools::RosoutSetupDialogBase in
> rosout_generated.cpp.o
> vtable for rxtools::TextboxDialog in
> rosout_generated.cpp.o
> vtable for rxtools::RosoutFrame in
> rosout_generated.cpp.o
> vtable for rxtools::LoggerLevelFrame in
> rosout_generated.cpp.o
> vtable for wxMDIParentFrameBase in
> rosout_generated.cpp.o
> ...
> "wxNavigationEnabled::AcceptsFocusRecursively()
> const", referenced from:
> vtable for rxtools::GenTopicDisplayDialog in
> topic_display_generated.cpp.o
> vtable for rxtools::TopicDisplayDialog in
> topic_display_dialog.cpp.o
> vtable for rxtools::RosoutSetupDialogBase in
> rosout_generated.cpp.o
> vtable for rxtools::TextboxDialog in
> rosout_generated.cpp.o
> vtable for rxtools::RosoutFrame in
> rosout_generated.cpp.o
> vtable for rxtools::LoggerLevelFrame in
> rosout_generated.cpp.o
> vtable for wxMDIParentFrameBase in
> rosout_generated.cpp.o
> ...
> "wxNavigationEnabled::AcceptsFocusFromKeyboard()
> const", referenced from:
> vtable for rxtools::GenTopicDisplayDialog in
> topic_display_generated.cpp.o
> vtable for rxtools::TopicDisplayDialog in
> topic_display_dialog.cpp.o
> vtable for rxtools::RosoutSetupDialogBase in
> rosout_generated.cpp.o
> vtable for rxtools::TextboxDialog in
> rosout_generated.cpp.o
> vtable for rxtools::RosoutFrame in
> rosout_generated.cpp.o
> vtable for rxtools::LoggerLevelFrame in
> rosout_generated.cpp.o
> vtable for wxMDIParentFrameBase in
> rosout_generated.cpp.o
> ...
> "wxNavigationEnabled::AddChild(wxWindowBase*)",
> referenced from:
> vtable for rxtools::GenTopicDisplayDialog in
> topic_display_generated.cpp.o
> vtable for rxtools::TopicDisplayDialog in
> topic_display_dialog.cpp.o
> vtable for rxtools::RosoutSetupDialogBase in
> rosout_generated.cpp.o
> vtable for rxtools::TextboxDialog in
> rosout_generated.cpp.o
> vtable for rxtools::RosoutFrame in
> rosout_generated.cpp.o
> vtable for rxtools::LoggerLevelFrame in
> rosout_generated.cpp.o
> vtable for wxMDIParentFrameBase in
> rosout_generated.cpp.o
> ...
> "wxNavigationEnabled::RemoveChild(wxWindowBase*)",
> referenced from:
> vtable for rxtools::GenTopicDisplayDialog in
> topic_display_generated.cpp.o
> vtable for rxtools::TopicDisplayDialog in
> topic_display_dialog.cpp.o
> vtable for rxtools::RosoutSetupDialogBase in
> rosout_generated.cpp.o
> vtable for rxtools::TextboxDialog in
> rosout_generated.cpp.o
> vtable for rxtools::RosoutFrame in
> rosout_generated.cpp.o
> vtable for rxtools::LoggerLevelFrame in
> rosout_generated.cpp.o
> vtable for wxMDIParentFrameBase in
> rosout_generated.cpp.o
> ...
> "wxRichTextCtrl::wxRichTextCtrl(wxWindow*,
> int, wxString const&, wxPoint const&,
> wxSize const&, long, wxValidator
> const&, wxString const&)", referenced
> from:
> rxtools::TextboxDialog::TextboxDialog(wxWindow*,
> int, wxString const&, wxPoint const&,
> wxSize const&, long) in
> rosout_generated.cpp.o
> "wxRichTextCtrl::ms_classInfo", referenced from:
> rxtools::TextboxDialog::onChar(wxKeyEvent&)
> in rosout_list_control.cpp.o
> "wxRichTextBuffer::BeginBold()", referenced from:
> wxRichTextCtrl::BeginBold() in rosout_list_control.cpp.o
> "wxRichTextBuffer::BeginTextColour(wxColour
> const&)", referenced from:
> wxRichTextCtrl::BeginTextColour(wxColour
> const&) in rosout_list_control.cpp.o
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
> invocation)
> make[2]: *** [lib/librxtools.dylib] Error 1
> make[1]: *** [rx/rxtools/CMakeFiles/rxtools.dir/all]
> Error 2
> make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
> Linking CXX shared library ../../../lib/librosbag.dylib
> [100%] Built target rosbag
> make: *** [all] Error 2

Just so you know I installed:

```
brew install boost

brew install log4cxx

brew install wxmac --devel --use-llvm
```

I installed: wxPython2.8-osx-unicode-py2.7

```
brew install GTest

brew install swig

brew install qt
```

Before Running:

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/ros/fuerte -DSETUPTOOLS_DEB_LAYOUT=OFF
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33754/ros-fuerte-on-lion-osx:-make--j8/) by [seanreynoldscs](https://answers.ros.org/users/2282/seanreynoldscs/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2012-05-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) on 2012-05-11**:
"symbols not found for architecture" makes it sound like you need a 64-bit (32-bit?) wx, maybe. Is there a universal version you can install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/OSX/Homebrew/Source

Use this install guide for lion for fuerte on osx.

---

Originally posted by [seanreynoldscs](https://answers.ros.org/users/2282/seanreynoldscs/) with karma: 46 on 2012-05-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1